Lineage 18 Stuck on Bootloop, Boot animation, Cannot open database code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN
Followed Lineageos instructions on how to build lineage18 for an emulator here.
All went well until when I get to final command emulator to launch the emulator when I noticed it was stuck in a bootloop for hours.
Using adb logcat, I was able to get the following stacktrace.
      *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider org.lineageos.lineagesettings.LineageSettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/user_de/0/org.lineageos.lineagesettings/databases/lineagesettings.db': Directory /data/user_de/0/org.lineageos.lineagesettings/databases doesn't exist
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6787)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installSystemProviders(ActivityThread.java:7439)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.installSystemProviders(ActivityManagerService.java:7972)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:1128)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:601)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)


      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/user_de/0/org.lineageos.lineagesettings/databases/lineagesettings.db': Directory /data/user_de/0/org.lineageos.lineagesettings/databases doesn't exist
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:762)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:751)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:373)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
        at org.lineageos.lineagesettings.LineageSettingsProvider.establishDbTracking(LineageSettingsProvider.java:767)
        at org.lineageos.lineagesettings.LineageSettingsProvider.onCreate(LineageSettingsProvider.java:115)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7246)
        ... 9 more


      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
        ... 24 more


This is where I am currently stuck.
